# Array.indexOf insensitive data type

Tags: javascript, types, indexof

I have been using `Array.indexOf` in the Google Chrome console, I tried these codes

```
[1,2,3].indexOf(3);
[1,2,"3"].indexOf("3");
```

They all returned 2, but when I tried these codes

```
[1,2,"3"].indexOf(3);
[1,2,3].indexOf("3");
```

They all returned -1. I want it also return 2, how could I do that? Thanks for your help, time, and effort!

Comment: change [1,2,"3"].indexOf("3"); and [1,2,3].indexOf(3);

Comment: probably just turn everything into a string then inside `indexOf`

Comment: Why are you storing different datatypes in the array? Can't you make sure that you convert everything to numbers first?

Comment: Good Idea, @A.Lau . Thanks A. Lau and Edison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

expanding on guest271314's post: cast both of the values to a string. This will also work for numbers and strings

```js
val = true

console.log([1,2,"true"].findIndex(item => String(item) === String(val)))
```

Comment: If you are converting value to string, use `===`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Array.prototype.findIndex()`, `==` operator

```js
var n = 3;

console.log(
  [1,2,3].findIndex(el => el == n)
, [1,2,"3"].findIndex(el => el == n)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort... it works  well between string and integer, but doesn't work well between boolean and string... But I appreciate your effort...

Comment: What do you mean by "between boolean and string"?

Comment: Sorry if my comment not really clear, this is an example var n = true;

console.log(  [1,2,true].findIndex(el => el == n), [1,2,"true"].findIndex(el => el == n))

Both returns 0.

Comment: That is a different requirement than original Question.